# No route matches POST for '/'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I feel like this is super easy, not sure why it's not working. In a view I have:

```
<%= form_tag(url: referrals_path, method: :post, :html => {:autocomplete => "off"}) %>
```

In routes I have:

```
post '/referrals', to: 'signups#referrals', as: "referrals"
```

Yet when I submit it says: `No route matches [POST] "/"`

The route doesn't conflict with anything else and is 2nd on the list after the root_path. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output from a rails console of `app.referrals_path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form tag to this:

```
<%= form_tag(referrals_path, :autocomplete => "off") %>
```

The first argument of form_tag is taken to be the URL, `post` is the default method for form_tag, and the hash of arguments at the end should automatically become HTML properties for the form.

Comment: Ok this worked, but to be honest, I'm very confused about why, since In another `form_tag` I also explicitly state the method and other such stuff. Literally to make this one I just copied and pasted from this one: `<%= form_tag(url: original_path, method: :post, :html => {:autocomplete => "off"}) %>`

Comment: I've never seen that format used for a `form_tag`, though it does look familiar from the `simple_form` gem (which I highly recommend to save time for building forms)